# ProcessBuilder not executing Java class file properly

Tags: java, windows, command-line, processbuilder

In a java file I am calling command line statement to execute another java file. This is what I am doing:

```
List<String> paramsExecute = new ArrayList<String>();
paramsExecute.add("java");
paramsExecute.add("-cp");
paramsExecute.add("input\programs\User_K Program1");
paramsExecute.add("1 2 3");

ProcessBuilder builderExecute = new ProcessBuilder(paramsExecute);

builderExecute.redirectOutput(new File(a.txt));
builderExecute.redirectError(new File(b.txt));
```

Execution of one of the Java files is producing b.txt as:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class 1 2 3
```

Another java file is producing b.txt as:

```
Usage: java [-options] class [args...] ...
```

But, when I am running these statements directly from the command line, it is executing correctly. The folder `input\programs\` is in the same path as the `src` folder. The `src` folder contains the Java file containing the ProcessBuilder program. I have verified that the .class file is getting created correctly and in the right folder. I am running the program in windows.

Any help appreciated!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This `paramsExecute.add("input\programs\User_K Program1");` is been treated as a single command/parameter, saying that the class path should be equal to `input\programs\User_K Program1`

I think you want to use something more like...

```
paramsExecute.add("input\programs\User_K");
paramsExecute.add("Program1");
```

Answer (score 1):

You should specify the classpath after '-cp' like

```
List<String> params = new ArrayList<String>();
params.add("java"); /* name of program to run, java */
params.add("-cp");  /* -cp */
params.add(System.getProperty("java.class.path")); /* class path information */
params.add("pkg.to.yourclass.ClassToRun"); /* full quailified class name */
params.add("1"); params.add("2"); params.add("3"); /* this is parameter to main */
```

**"input\programs\User_K Program1"** in your code is treated as a classpath information, not class to run because it follows '-cp', and **"1 2 3"** as a class name, not arguments passed to the main method.

It is not easy to retrieve classpath from the scatch.

If you want to create a process using an class located in the sample src folder, It is good to use **`System.getProperty("java.class.path");`** to inherite classpath, or You should type the path info manually.