# Get output java complie from cmd

Tags: java

I have a project that use command prompt to complie java file,then print the result in console,this is mycode.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String line;
    String output = "";
    try {
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java helloworld");
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
            output += (line + '\n');
        }            
        input.close();           
        }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.print(output);
    }
```

But it show nothing,although it work with another command,please help me.

Comment: What about [`STDERR`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#getErrorStream())? You need to read from **both** output streams, **at the same time**. Please read [this excellent article](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html) on the correct usage of `Runtime.exec`. It's new a little dated, and there are much better threading APIs available - but it gives you a taste of the complexities of what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thank you,new knowledge for me

Answer (score 1):

As one of the commenters mentioned this might result in quite complex setups you are running into. It is most likely in your case that an error happens in java and you just do not see the output since error messages are written to the STDERR stream instead of STDOUT.

So there are two options (1) you take the code you already have and also try to read from the process' ErrorStream.

```
Bufferedreader error = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream());
```

Or if you do not care whether or not the process you were starting was writing to STDERR or to STDOUT you can also use a ProcessBuilder and just set it up to redirect the error stream.

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("java", "helloworld");
pb.redirectErrorStream(true); // this redirects STDERR to STDOUT
Process p = pb.start();
BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
    output += (line + '\n');
}            
input.close();
```

For the sake of simplicity I omitted all the boilerplate code and exception handling in the above. But I think you will get the idea.

Comment: Yes,i'm was try with option 1,and i get a error that not show before.It's show "Error: Could not find or load main class helloworld",but i can run direct in command prompt

Comment: @john this is now a classpath issue, post a new question.

Comment: My command prompt default set path to C:\Users\john ,and i put my class file in there,i think when i use "Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java helloworld");" it use that path,but it wrong

Comment: As Boris mentioned this is now a problem with the CLASSPATH i.e. of the parameters that you are adding to ProcessBuilder. See for instance the following question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22137387/processbuilder-not-executing-java-class-file-properly

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using the Process builder and executing the same. Why not use [JavaCompiler](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html) interface. See the documentation it is really well written.